# serializing and deserializing object that contains a list of himself

Tags: java, serialization

how can I de/serialize a class in java that contains a list of that exact class as a member? this is an example:

```
public class Target implements Serializable {
    private final String name;
    private List<Target> dependsOnList = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<Target> requiredFor = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Is it even possible? it fills like an endless recursion and i just cant figure it out

thanks in advance

Comment: Need to keep track of visited nodes.

Comment: @DaveNewton I thought Java serialisation did that for you already?

Comment: Oh I thought the OP was implementing their own recursive functionality.

Comment: @DaveNewton what do you mean?
should i do it in a loop? 
wouldnt it still be uneffective(it would still be calling the serializer recursivley)

Comment: Yes, Java serialization (that is, ObjectOutputStream) already tracks this in a safe manner.  No special precautions are needed.  If you are talking about something like XML serialization or JSON serialization, that might be a different matter.

Comment: @VGR I guess the key line from the manual on ObjectOutputStream is, "Multiple references to a single object are encoded using a reference sharing mechanism so that graphs of objects can be restored to the same shape as when the original was written." I take that to mean that, if there is circularity in the object such that it refers back to itself, that's just fine.

Comment: @bazza Exactly correct.